# i have a problem while calculate WPL of huffmantree

Tags: c, algorithm

```
pStack initStack() {
    pStack s = (pStack)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    s->top = -1;
    s->stelem[0] = NULL;
    return s;
}
int isEmpty(pStack stack) {
    if (stack->top == -1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
int isFull(pStack stack) {
    if (stack->top == maxsize - 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
int Push(pStack* s, pTree a) {

    if (isFull(*s)) {
        return -1;//异常返回-1
    }
    else {
        (*s)->stelem[++((*s)->top)] = a;
        return 1;
    }  
}
int Pop(pStack* s, pTree* a) {
    if (isEmpty(*s)) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        *a = (*s)->stelem[((*s)->top)--];
        return 1;
    }
}
void preorder(pTree* t) {
    int h=0;//深度
    pStack s = initStack();
    pTree p = (*t);
    while (p != NULL||s->top!=-1) {
        while (p != NULL) {
            //访问根节点
            if (p->elem != NULL) {
                printf("%c ", p->elem->data);
                printf("%d ", p->elem->count);
                
                    WPL = WPL + (s->top + 1) * (p->elem->count);
                
            }
            
            Push(&s, p);
            
            p = p->leftChild;
            //遍历左子树
            
        }
        //遍历右子树
        if (s->top != -1) {
            
            Pop(&s, &p);//pop会导致top改变，遍历右子树计算wpl出问题
            //the problem is here
            p = p->rightChild;
            
        }
    }
}
```

The pre-order traversal of the stack to access the right subtree will cause s->top--, which will cause problems in the calculation of wpl.
hope a Big guy come and help me!

The pre-order traversal of the stack to access the right subtree will cause s->top--, which will cause problems in the calculation of wpl.
How to ensure that the height of the node will not be affected?

Comment: It's better for the community if all comments are in English, which is [easy](https://translate.google.com/?sl=auto&tl=en&text=%E9%81%8D%E5%8E%86%E5%B7%A6%E5%AD%90%E6%A0%91&op=translate) today.